# Get magit views in to bookmarks plus

Tags: magit, bookmarks

After doing some changes in a git "feature branch", I use "magit diff" to review/cleanup before pushing code to GitHub.

My question is

a) How can I get this ^ magit buffer in to my bookmarks+ (<kbd>C-x r l</kbd>) bookmarks

Answer (score 2):

Bookmarks to Magit buffers are implemented so it works the same way as for any other type of bookmark: type <kbd>C-x r m</kbd> while in the buffer you want to bookmark.